# Python Flask / Sqlite: How to embed images in a post content

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am new in programming and in Python Flask and I am trying to design a blog as first project. I was able to create a page ("Add") directly connected to my SQLite database in order to write and publish the post directly there. The problem is that I have not thought that I would also like to add images within the text content and I have no idea how to do it. This is my main page:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime




 
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/admin/Desktop/Blog_Project/blog2.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost2(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

db.create_all() 

@app.route('/')
def index():

    posts = Blogpost.query.all()

    return render_template('index.html', posts = posts)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
    

#@app.route('/post')
#def post():
    #return render_template('post.html')

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def post(post_id):
    post = Blogpost2.query.filter_by(id=post_id).one()

    date_posted = post.date_posted.strftime('%d %B, %Y')

    return render_template('post.html', post=post, date_posted = date_posted)


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')


@app.route('/prova')
def prova():
    return render_template('prova.html')


@app.route('/add')
def add():
    return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    
    title = request.form['title']
    subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
    author = request.form["author"]
    content = request.form['content']


    #return '<h1>Title:{} Subtitle:{} Author:{} Content:{} <h1/>'.format(title, subtitle, author, content)
    post = Blogpost2(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=author, content=content, date_posted = datetime.now())


    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    

    return redirect(url_for('index'))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

As you can see, the blog title, subtitle, author, content, and so on would be entered in the SQLlite database. That would happen trough the "Add" page, of which here you can see the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <!-- <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <!--  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">                              -->
  <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'fontawesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'clean-blog.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

   <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href= "{{ url_for('index') }}">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about')}}">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('contact')}}">Contact</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('prova')}}">Prova</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Header -->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/contact-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="page-heading">
            <h1>Aggiungi un post </h1>
            <span class="subheading"> </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <form name="addForm" id="addForm" method = "POST" action= "{{ url_for('addpost') }}" novalidate>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name = "title" id="title" required data-validation-required-message="Dai un titolo al tuo post">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Subtitle</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subtitle" name = "subtitle" id="subtitle" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Author</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Author" name = "author" id="author" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Blog Content</label>
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Blog content" name = "content" id="content" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="success"></div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <!-- Qua inizia la parte inferiore-->
          <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

          

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src= "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'jquery.min.js')}}"> </script>
  <script src= "{{ url_for('static', filename = 'bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
  

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'clean-blog.min.js')}}"> </script>>

</body>

</html>
```

But is there a way to embed images within the post content? Or maybe should I choose another way to display text and images together?
Thank you very much in advance, every suggestion would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need a way to upload an image. You can do this in several ways; Stack Overflow uses links to hosted images which are rendered with the `src` attribute of the `img` tag. Or you could get your user to upload an image.

Once you've validated the image chosen (if it's being uploaded), you should add it to your flask static folder, or from wherever you serve static files, and add a field that looks something like this to your `db.Model`:

```
image_path = db.Column(db.String(128)) # swap 128 for something suitable to your path length
```

Then, you can use the HTML `img` tag and its attribute `src` to get the image from your server like this:

```html
<h1>{{ blog.author.name }} says: </h1>
<h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
<p>
    {{ blog.content }}
</p>
<img src="{{ blog.image_path }}">
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand how I can recall the images from the fill form "Blog content" in the add page, which is alread dynamic. If I want, say, the combination, text-image-text-image, how can I do it inside the text content? Or may I  use the img tag directly in the add page? The problem is that my posts would be saved directly in the DB.

Comment: ah so you want your post content to actually contain the image? That's quite a bit harder to do, because instead of processing raw plaintext as the document is doing, you need to parse a string of a path to an image which is in the post body and make sure that it actually gets rendered as an image rather than as a string saying where the image is. You could use markup ([get started here](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started/)) to take an image tag and turn it into an actual image